# How to get the value from file in C?

Tags: c

I have a program to get the value from a file (name input.inp). This file have 3 value : 10  20   cat.
I want to get these value by call the function readfile and **print the value in main()**.
But this not work. I hope someone can help me to solve this problem. Thankyou so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_file(int *a, int *b, char c[]) {
FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("input.inp", "r");
    if(f1 == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
    fscanf(f1, "%d", &a);
    fscanf(f1, "%d", &b);
    fscanf(f1, "[^\n]", &c);    
    }
    fclose(f1);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    char c[100];
    read_file(&a, &b, c);     
    printf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d",&b);
    printf("%s",&c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(f1, "%d", &a);` should be `fscanf(f1, "%d", a);` and others too

Comment: `fscanf(f1, "[^\n]", &c);` ==> `fscanf(f1, "[^\n]", c);` as well.

Comment: If the 3 items in the file are on separate lines, the third specifier needs a space to eat the previous newline like `fscanf(f1, " [^\n]", c); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change these

```
 fscanf(f1, "%d", &a);
 fscanf(f1, "%d", &b);
 fscanf(f1, "[^\n]", &c);
```

into

```
 fscanf(f1, "%d", a);
 fscanf(f1, "%d", b);
 fscanf(f1, "%[^\n]s", c);
```

and these

```
 printf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d",&b);
    printf("%s",&c);
```

into

```
 printf("%d",a);
 printf("%d",b);
 printf("%s",c);
```

better add `\n` for every output ,so that you see neatly.

Comment: Without the `"%[^\n]s"`, `[^\n]` will not read anything into `c`.

Comment: Right @BoR. I overlooked , it was a quick answer

Comment: Thanks @IrAM and Bo R so much. It work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Safer is to specify what type of array `read_file` accepts so you don't overwrite the buffer.

Also, `fscanf(f1, "%s", *c)` will read in the string to the *pointer* to the array, thus the `*c`. And using `"%99s"` just limits the reading to max 99 characters leaving room for the null terminator.

Decorating your `printf` to see where the values are comming from.

```c
#define THE_FILE "input.inp"

int read_file(int* a, int* b, char (*c)[100])
{
   FILE* f1 = fopen(THE_FILE, "r");
   if(f1 == NULL)
   {
      perror("fopen failed to open `" THE_FILE "'");
      return -1;
   }
   fscanf(f1, "%d %d %99s", a, b, *c);
   fclose(f1);
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   int a = 0, b = 0;
   char c[100];
   if(read_file(&a, &b, &c) == -1)
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   printf("a: %d b: %d c: `%s'", a, b, c);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```